# Deploying Express server with Mongoose to Netlify

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, netlify

I am able to deploy an Express server with netlify using this tutorial: https://paulreaney.medium.com/deploy-express-js-on-netlify-91cfaea39591

When I add Mongoose to the server I get a crash notification and a timeout.

[image: Server Timeout]

I then tried installing `mongodb-client-encryption` but same error.

Is it possible to have an express server that calls a MongoDB collection hosted on Netlify?

If there is other information I can share to aid with this please tell me and I will!

Thanks
Tim

Edit: To clarify, when I run the express server on my local it works perfectly.

Comment: I would recommend using Heroku and Mongo cloud instead. Netlify is great for the frontend part. But deploying backend, especially with a database, is cumbersome and not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, there were two issues, both causing the function calls to take more than 10 seconds so it was timing out.

The first issue was the simplest, I hadn't allowed any IP address to query the database on my MongoDB dashboard.

The second issue was I hadn't set my handler up properly to interact with asynchronous functions (which mongoose uses).
Here is the code I used to fix it:

Before:

```
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

After:

```
const handler = serverless(app);
module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const result = await handler(event, context);
  return result;
};
```